# Read millions of small files and insert into mysql with Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous, data-science

I've tried many ways but can't find an efficient and performant way to open millions of files in a folder and insert their content into a database with nodejs.

It needs to be memory efficient and asynchronous because of SQL queries.

Any insight ?

Comment: Best show some of the things you tried, otherwise the question may be too vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are not creating an app but more of a one time migration right?

If you are going to just let NodeJS read everything at once and insert to DB using a simple JS loop, you are probably going to face errors.

1. Either your DB will hang due to insufficient memory / choke up due to too many connections at once.
2. NodeJS is lightweight.. it just reads the "million of files"

My take on this vague question is that you need to control the insertion:

You can use modules like https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/ to help you control which calls are asynchronous or synchronous using `async.eachSeries()` or `async.waterfall()`

Reading files you can use the Nodejs' fs module which can be found here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_file_system.htm

If you can't control what files your NodeJS is reading, you can.

1. Read a few files, store it in batches of JSON arrays or objects
2. Insert them asynchronously / synchronously using the method mentioned above.

This implementation is totally up to how you nest each read and write.

Cheers